# Don't have ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, crm

Im trying build an HTML page that I will pass to IVR and in turn it will open a Contact form on an incoming call.

The HTML page includes a simple JS method that runs a query for Contacts with ID that is passed to the URL of the HTML.

for this i need to use XrmServiceToolkit.js which i have, but, XrmServiceToolkit.js uses GetGlobalContext method that is located in the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx.

I cant find ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx, it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af74d417-1359-4eaa-9f87-5b33a8852e83#BKMK_ClientGlobalContext_js_aspx) that it is located at the root of the web resources directory.

I looked in the web resources directory of my VS2012 solution and its not there.

Am I missing something? 
Is there a place where I can download that ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx?
How does the ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx gets to the web resources directory in the first place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Referring the "ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" in HTML web resource depends on the web resource name formats.

http://crm2011developersblog.blogspot.pt/2012/07/different-ways-to-refer.html

Comment: Thank you, what wasn't clear to me is that the ClientGlobalContext is in the web resources by default. I assumed it should be added. I was looking for it, and I wanted to actually see the file itself and the GGetGlobalContext method. Thank you again.